Entity Framework SQLite concurrency error while saving changes
i am making a server app and its logic DOES work while i'm adding a new user but when i add a new item to the shopping cart everything messes up. i get a concurrency error while i save changes.
    public static async Task<bool> TryAddUserAsync(string name, string email, string password)
        {
            using (var database = new Database())
            {
                try
                {
                    var existingUser = await database.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email);
                    if (existingUser != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("User with this email already exists.");
                        return false;
                    }

                    var user = new User() { Email = email, Name = name, Password = password, Role = "Customer" };
                    database.Users.Add(user);
                    database.ShoppingCarts.Add(new ShoppingCart() { Id = user.Id, View = new List<MedicineShoppingCartView>() });
                    await database.SaveChangesAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS SIGN UP");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

this is my adding users logic. it works. and this is my adding to cart logic. it DOES NOT work:
 public async static Task<bool> TryAddToCartAsync(int id, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var database = new Database())
                {
                    // Начинаем транзакцию
                    using (var transaction = database.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        // Получаем пользователя
                        var user = await database.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == key);

                        if (user == null)
                            return false;

                        
                        var cart = await database.ShoppingCarts.Include(sc => sc.View)
                                                .Where(u => u.Id == user.Id)
                                                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                        // Пытаемся получить товар из базы данных
                        var medicine = await GetByIdFromDatabaseAsync(id);
                        if (medicine == null)
                            return false;

                        // Ищем товар в корзине пользователя
                        var existingItem = cart.View.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
                        if (existingItem != null)
                        {
                            // Увеличиваем количество товара, если он уже есть в корзине
                            existingItem.Count += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Добавляем товар в корзину, если его там нет
                            cart.View.Add(new MedicineShoppingCartView() { Id = medicine.Id, Count = 1 });
                        }

                        // Сохраняем изменения в базе данных
                        await database.SaveChangesAsync();

                        // Фиксируем транзакцию
                        transaction.Commit();

                        return true; // Операция выполнена успешно
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Обработка ошибок
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }


this is where i use this function:
private async Task AddToCartAsync(JsonElement jsonObject, NetworkStream stream)
    {
        if (!jsonObject.TryGetProperty("Id", out JsonElement js_id))
            return;
        
        var id = js_id.GetInt32();
        
        var add_result = await Manager.TryAddToCartAsync(id, key);
        
        byte[] dataToSend;
        if (add_result)
        {
            dataToSend = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes<int>((int)SentDataMessages.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            dataToSend = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes<int>((int)SentDataMessages.ERROR);
        }
        await stream.WriteAsync(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
    }

the main function:
private async Task HandleClientAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
            int bytesRead;
            
            while (!breakpoint && (bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if (breakpoint)
                    break;
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                byte[] dataToSend = new byte[1];
                var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(data);
                int query_code = jsonObject.GetProperty("QueryType").GetInt32();
                var user_name = string.Empty;
                var user_login = string.Empty;
                var user_password = string.Empty;
                var category = string.Empty;
                int count = 0;
                int id = 0;
                switch (query_code)
                {
                    case (int)QueryTypes.EXIT:
                        Exit(client, stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.LOGIN:
                        await LoginAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.REGISTER:
                        await RegisterAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;

                    case (int)QueryTypes.SEARCH:
                        await SearchAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.GET_CART:
                        await GetCartAsync(stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.GET_BY_ID:
                        await GetByIdAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;

                    case (int)QueryTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
                        await AddToCartAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.DELETE_FROM_CART:
                        await DeleteFromCartAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;
                    case (int)QueryTypes.SET_CART_ITEM_COUNT:
                        await SetCartItemCountAsync(jsonObject, stream);
                        break;
                }
            }

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
        }

    }

i tried to lock the thread, to make everyting async and to use transaction. nothing works.

The entire design is wrong. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It doesn't need explicit transactions because all pending transactions, to all entities, are persisted in a single internal transaction when SaveChanges is called. Until then, no database connection is used. In server-based databases the question's code would result in delays, scaling problems and occasional deadlocks. SQLite is a single-user database though, and attempts at concurrent access result in errors, not blocks. This long lived transaction increases the chance of errors exponentially

^^ Not to mention storing the clear text password. If you don't care for a password too much, don't use one. If you do, do it right.

chat gpt told me to use transaction, my teacher said it's a bad idea. but i'm not sure that the concurrency error reason is the transaction way. the error did appear without it either. what should i do instead?

what about the clearing text password? can you please tell more about it? is it something ebout infosequirity?

@maryjane instead of using statistically generated text, listen to your teacher and actually read the docs to understand what's going on. Statistical text generators understand nothing, they just generate words one after another based on your input text and the text they were trained on. If it's trained on a lot of bad code and bad blogs, the response will contain bad code as well. And guess what, a lot of people don't read the docs, assume EF is a database driver and start using it this way, adding useless transactions

@maryjane just adding Assume I'm an experienced EF developer that knows how the optimistic concurrency model works can affect the generated output and result in a better example than whatever you tried. Just talking about optimistic concurrency eliminates a lot of the bad blogs, simply because they don't contain those words or synonyms

In this line:
cart.View.Add(new MedicineShoppingCartView() { Id = medicine.Id, Count = 1 });

Medicine shopping cart ID is set to medicine ID, when another user adds the same item the ID will be duplicated.
In medicine shopping cart you would need columns:

Id
MedicineId
Count (Quantity)

